# WHM API: Find cPanel user by domain

Tags: php, api, cpanel, whm

I'm working on a WHM API and want to find the cPanel username by passing the domain name.

**NOTE**: I've the credentials of WHM.

There is no such documentation exists here https://documentation.cpanel.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1507786

So, is there a way to achieve do so?

**Update:**

Now, I'm using [xmlapi.php](https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php) and here is what I tried so far.

```
    require_once(base_path() . "/vendor/cpanel_api/xmlapi.php");
    $ip = env('SERVER_IP', "127.0.0.1"); //your server's IP

    $xmlapi = new \xmlapi($ip);
    $xmlapi->password_auth(env('CPANEL_USER', "root"),env('CPANEL_PASSWORD', "")); //the server login info for the user you want to create the emails under

    $xmlapi->set_output('json');
    $xmlapi->set_debug(1);

    $params = array('domain'=>$domain, 'searchtype'=>'domain'); //quota is in MB
    $res = json_decode($xmlapi->api2_query('root', "listaccts", "", $params), true);


    print_r($res);
```

in `$xmlapi->api2_query` method, there are 4 arguments

- cPanel Username
- WHM Module Name
- Function under the Given Module in step 2
- parameters, that'll be passed to the function in step 3

I have to find out the cPanel Username, so, I wrote the 'root' for now. but no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give a try with cPanel API.

Here are the some useful docs of API.

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Guide+to+cPanel+API+2
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Guide+to+WHM+API+1